# Как перемешать 2 строки

Tags: java

Почему массив `arrayC` запоминает только по одному элементу из каждого массива?
Я планировал перемешать 2 строки.

```
public static void mixString(String a, String b) {
    String[] arrayA = a.split("");
    String[] arrayB = b.split("");
    String[] arrayC = new String[a.length() + b.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayC.length - 1; i++) {
        getTurn();
        if (f) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayA.length; j++)
                arrayC[i] = arrayA[j];
        }
        else {
            for (int x = 0; x < arrayB.length; x++)
                arrayC[i] = arrayB[x];
        }
    }
}

public static boolean getTurn() {
    f = !f;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: потому что ты всегда кладешь только последний элемент из других массивов в ячейку `arrayC`

Comment: Почему, Склифосовский?

Comment: Потому что ты так задал)))

Comment: Ооо...мне полегчало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
public static void mixString(String a, String b) {
  char[] arrayC = new char[a.length() + b.length()];
  int idxA = 0;
  int idxB = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayC.length; i++) {
    if (idxB >= b.length() || (idxA < a.length() && getTurn()))
      arrayC[i] = a.charAt(idxA++);
    else
      arrayC[i] = b.charAt(idxB++);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Разбивать строку на массив строк с помощью `split` для работы с конкретными символами строки является весьма неоптимальным вариантом. Для этого в классе `String` существует метод [charAt(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)).

Для работы с набором символов в данном случае лучше воспользоваться массивом символов `char[]`, а не массивом строк `String[]`, состоящих из одного символа.

Для создания строки из массива символов существует метод [String.valueOf(char[] data)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char[])).

В итоге получается такой код:

```
public static String mixString(String a, String b)
{
    char[] resultChars = new char[a.length() + b.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < resultChars.length; i++)
    {
        resultChars[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? a.charAt(i / 2) : b.charAt(i / 2);
    }
    return String.valueOf(resultChars);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, дружище!

Answer (score 0):

Написав

```
for (int j = 0; j<arrayA.length; j++)
    arrayC[i] = arrayA[j];
```

происходит выполнение цикла количество раз равное `arrayA.length`. При этом каждый элемент из массива `arrayA` кладется постоянно в одну и ту же ячейку `arrayC[i]`. В итоге когда цикл заканчивается в ячейке оказывается лишь последний элемент массива. И так постоянно.

Аналогично и с `arrayB`

Comment: Почему i++ не работает?

Comment: @OldHuman почему же, работает..... ты пробегаешься по `arrayC` но при этом в каждую ячейку попадает лишь последний элемент другого массива, потому что всегда вторые циклы работают вхолостую кладя лишь последний элемент в ячейку `arrayC[i]`

Comment: Спасибо, блин я такой лошара((

Comment: @OldHuman со всеми бывает. Просто почитай информацию про отладку (Debugging) приложения и тогда не придется постоянно такие вопросы на форумах задавать и сможешь прослеживать построчно выполнение своей программы сам.